# How can I get a value from a JSON with a partially field name

Tags: java, json

I have a JSON with field name which I dont know its exact name. I know that they contain `Body` and `Header` (that's it for now). Each of this fields contain a `JSONObject`.

What is the most efficient way to get the `JSONObject` by using the strings `Header` and `Body`?

My idea was to iterate the json keys with `keyIterator()` and for each key (which is a `String`) to check if it contains the partial name:

```
iterator.next().contains("Header")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be no more efficient way than looping through them all and applying your custom test. If you're looking for `"header"` and `"body"`, you can at least use the same iterator.

Even if the json library supported this search method, this would probably be what would happen underneath as there would be no easy way of ordering them to make the look up faster.

If this was `startsWith`, you could have them sorted alphabetically and the find can be made faster. Of course the act of sorting them is then the expensive part, so it would only make sense if you were doing many lookups.

It's hard to decide which is "most efficient", so go with the simple loop, then profile your whole application and find where effort can be best spent to provide speed improvements.